# Complex mongodb query with objects of varying keynames and arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My question has two parts. My document structure is below.

1. I would essentially like to query the items of the array `foo.*.bar.*`. How can I even access `bar` in a query if the keys of `foo` (i.e. the parent of `bar`) are different for each document?
2. In particular, `bar` is a variable length array. The items that `bar` can hold are from a fixed set (e.g. `cat`, `dog`, `cow` etc). And `bar` might have any number of these, in any order. I would like to query: **the documents that have *only one `bar`* which contains one or more of a particular item**. E.g. `cat` => It would return Document #2. (Even though it has two `cats` in one `bar`, it has only one `bar` with `cats`.

To make this clearer, here is the pseudo-code for the predicate: I

```
predictate(document, item):
    bars_which_contain_item = 0
    foreach currentFoo in document.foo:
       if currentFoo.bar.contains(item) bars_which_contain_item += 1
    return bars-which-contain-item == 1;
```

I've looked at the documentation regarding querying [arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/), [embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/) and [arrays of embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/), but I couldn't find an answer. Is what I want to do even possible? Or do I need to add a pass which runs over all of my data and adds numberOfCats, numberofDogs, numberOfCows fields to allow this kind of querying in the future? (I won't need to do this kind of querying often, and performance is not too important).

P.S. I'm using nodejs, but I guess the query structure won't change too much. (Besides, if I can do the query in MongoDB Compass, that's even better).

> ```
> {
>    _id: 1,
>    foo: {
>       a : { bar: ['cat', 'dog', 'cow'] },
>       b : { bar: ['cat', 'cat', 'dog'] },
>    }
> },
> {
>    _id: 2,
>    foo: {
>       c : { bar: ['cow'] },
>       d : { bar: ['dog'] },
>       e : { bar: ['cow'] },
>       f : { bar: ['cat', 'dog', 'cat'] },
>    }
> },
> {
>    _id: 3,
>    foo: {
>       g : { bar: ['cat', 'cow'] },
>       h : { bar: ['cow'] },
>       i : { bar: ['cat'] },
>    }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/.

```
r = db.foo.aggregate([
  {$project: {foo: {$objectToArray: '$foo'}}},
  {$project: {foo: '$foo.v'}},
])

# =>

{"_id":1,"foo":[{"bar":["cat","dog","cow"]},{"bar":["cat","cat","dog"]}]}
{"_id":2,"foo":[{"bar":["cow"]},{"bar":["dog"]},{"bar":["cow"]},{"bar":["cat","dog","cat"]}]}
{"_id":3,"foo":[{"bar":["cat","cow"]},{"bar":["cow"]},{"bar":["cat"]}]}
```

For your second question:

```
r = db.foo.aggregate([
  {$project: {foo: {$objectToArray: '$foo'}}},
  {$project: {foo: '$foo.v'}},
  {$project: {foo: {$cond: {
    if: {eq: ['cat', '$foo.bar']},
    then: '$foo.bar',
    else: '$$REMOVE',
  }}}},
  {$project: {foo: {$filter: {
    input: '$foo',
    as: 'x',
    cond: {$in: ['cat', '$$x']},
  }}}},
  {$match: {foo: {$size: 1}}},
])


{"_id":2,"foo":[["cat","dog","cat"]]}
```

Comment: wow, thanks, it will take me a while to ingest this.